# Use Angular 9 Slice Pipe in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I'm having trouble finding a solution for using the Slice pipe from Angular within a for loop.

**Imagine following code:**

```
textArray = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccccccccccc'];
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of textArray">
    {{ text | slice:0:20 }}
</ng-container>
```

I don't want to use the pipe on every single element of the array, but i'd like to use the pipe on the combined textvalues of the for-loop. Anyone tips or a solution?

Kind regards

Comment: Build the combined text values in the ts file, there is no need to use a *ngFor here

Comment: I ended up doing what you said, the least amount of drama, but hoped there would be a straight up solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use it inside ngFor

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let text of textArray | slice:0:20">
   {{text}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately. But I solved it another way, thanks for responding!